# How to change the icon or color of the icon for each file using material-ui-dropzone

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-dropzone

I am using [material-ui-dropzone](https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-ui-dropzone) to upload multiple files.

Is there any way to change the icon or color of the icon for each file?

Please give me suggestion to solve this problem.

Current situation -
[image]

Code example -  [Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-dropzone-gby09?file=/src/index.js)

Comment: You can check their documents in https://yuvaleros.github.io/material-ui-dropzone/ 'Custom Preview Icon' section

Answer (score 0):

First if you see the example in the documentation https://react-dropzone.js.org/#section-previews

instead of using thumbnail use an icon from material UI and update the color programmatically.

Create a color pallet or a function that returns you the RGB programmatically. Then assign the color to each icon when you mount an icon component based on the number of file.

for simple one just create an array with color values:

`const colorPallet = ['red', 'yello', 'green', ... ]`

and assign the color in style `<FileClipIcon style={{ color: colorPallet[index] }} />`

otherwise write a function which returns you random RGB values between 0 to 255 and use that.